# Can't have 2 dynamic text fields AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

This is not a specific situation, this is something that happens a lot to me.

Whenever I have dynamic text (that changes through code, of course) everything works fine.
However, when I add a second Dynamic text, both of them do not show.
An example scenario would be:

```
textfield1.text="hello";
```

and on the next frame

```
textfield2.text="goodbye";
```

no text would show.
Something is wrong with flash, maybe. The problem starts when I add another textbox to the stage.

I do not want to upgrade to a newer flash, but I could if I have to.

If anybody knows how to fix my problem, please tell me.

Comment: are you using the `embed fonts` option?

Comment: What is your version of flash pro? Are the Textfields placed on your timelide (so you have to embed fonts and add the Font to the library) or added by code? What happens if you try "trace(textfield2); before "textfield2.text="goodbye";"?
Could you edit your question, please and tell more about your issue?

Comment: @www0z0k If an instance of a TextField (marked as Dynamic) is manually added to the Timeline without embedding fonts, I think that I should throw an Error like this "Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts."

Comment: Are the linkage names of these two Textfields really textfield1 and textfield2? I believe if you copy the first one it will keep the linkage name of the original?

Comment: @Philarmon nope, I've tried it and posted as a second answer.
If the instances are properly named, this works as a charm. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that embed fonts is optional if you create and add an instance of TextField trough AS3 (excepts if you specify a font that is not present on another computer).

In the example here bellow, the text for textfield1 and textfield2 is always displayed, so I probably misunderstand your question.
Best regards.
Nicolas

PS : the "var timer:Timer" and the callback function are only used to make this example switch an loop from frame 1 to frame 2

**Example 1**

frame 1:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

if (! textfield1 && ! textfield2)
{
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    var textfield1:TextField = new TextField();
    var textfield2:TextField = new TextField();

    var tfPosition:Point = new Point(100,50);
}
try{
    removeChild(textfield2);
}catch(e:Error){
    (trace ("   ERROR : textfield2 is not already added"));
}
addChild(textfield1);
textfield1.x = tfPosition.x;
textfield1.y = tfPosition.y;
textfield1.text = "hello";

stop();

function playStop(te:TimerEvent):void{
    play();
}

if(!timer){
    var timer:Timer=new Timer(1000);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,playStop);
    timer.start();
}
```

frame 2 :

```
removeChild(textfield1);
addChild(textfield2);
textfield2.x = tfPosition.x;
textfield2.y = tfPosition.y;
textfield2.text="goodbye";
stop();
```

**Example 2**

If you have two instances of a TextField manually placed on the Timeline, that you select "use device fonts" and the names for the instances are really called "textfield1" on the first frame and "textfield2" on the second frame.
(I've done it by copy and paste in place and didn't get any issue neither).

This works on CS6 too... The text is well displayed

So give us more details please.

Instance of TextField on frame 1 named "textfield1"
code on frame 1 :

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

textfield1.text = "hello";
stop();
function playStop(te:TimerEvent):void {
    play();
}

if (! timer)
{
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,playStop);
    timer.start();
}
```

Instance of TextField on frame 2 named "textfield2"
code on frame 2 :

```
textfield2.text="goodbye";
stop();
```

Comment: @Zane Clark did you fix your issue?